# R: Performance issue when finding maximum of splitted list

Tags: r, performance, list, split, lapply

When trying to find the maximum values of a splitted list, I run into serious performance issues.

Is there a way I can optimize the following code:

```
# Generate data for this MWE
x <- matrix(runif(900 * 9000), nrow = 900, ncol = 9000)
y <- rep(1:100, each = 9)
my_data <- cbind(y, x)
my_data <- data.frame(my_data)

# This is the critical part I would like to optimize
my_data_split <- split(my_data, y)
max_values <- lapply(my_data_split, function(x) x[which.max(x[ , 50]), ])
```

I want to get the rows where a given column hits its maximum for a given group (it should be easier to understand from the code).

I know that splitting into a list is probably the reason for the slow performance, but I don't know how to circumvent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be immediately clear to you.

There is an internal function `max.col` doing something similar, except that it finds position index of the maximum along a matrix row (not column). So if you transpose your original matrix `x`, you will be able to use this function.

Complexity steps in when you want to do `max.col` by group. The `split`-`lapply` convention is needed. But, if after the transpose, we convert the matrix to a data frame, we can do `split.default`. (*Note it is not `split` or `split.data.frame`. Here the data frame is treated as a list (vector), so the split happens among the data frame columns.*) Finally, we do an `sapply` to apply `max.col` by group and `cbind` the result into a matrix.

```
tx <- data.frame(t(x))
tx.group <- split.default(tx, y)  ## note the `split.default`, not `split`
pos <- sapply(tx.group, max.col)
```

The resulting `pos` is something like a look-up table. It has 9000 rows and 100 columns (groups). The `pos[i, j]` gives the index you want for the `i`-th column (of your original non-transposed matrix) and `j`-th group. So your final extraction for the 50-th column and all groups is

```
max_values <- Map("[[", tx.group, pos[50, ])
```

You just generate the look-up table once, and make arbitrary extraction at any time.

---

**Disadvantage of this method:**

After the split, data in each group are stored in a data frame rather than a matrix. That is, for example, `tx.group[[1]]` is a 9000 x 9 data frame. But `max.col` expects a matrix so it will convert this data frame into a matrix internally.

Thus, the major performance / memory overhead includes:

- initial matrix transposition;
- matrix to data frame conversion;
- data frame to matrix conversion (per group).

I am not sure whether we eliminate all above with some functions from `MatrixStats` package. I look forward to seeing a solution with that.

But anyway, this answer is already much faster than what OP originally does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using {dplyr}:

```
# Generate data for this MWE
x <- matrix(runif(900 * 9000), nrow = 900, ncol = 9000)
y <- rep(1:100, each = 9)
my_data <- cbind.data.frame(y, x)

# This is the critical part I would like to optimize
system.time({
  my_data_split <- split(my_data, y)
  max_values <- lapply(my_data_split, function(x) x[which.max(x[ , 50]), ])
})

# Using {dplyr} is 9 times faster, but you get results in a slightly different format
library(dplyr)
system.time({
  max_values2 <- my_data %>%
    group_by(y) %>%
    do(max_values = .[which.max(.[[50]]), ])
})

all.equal(max_values[[1]], max_values2$max_values[[1]], check.attributes = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think that I should begin using the dplyr package, because it is in widespread use and has a very clear synthax.